# Making a Kotlin Function Accept a String as an Object Reference

Tags: class, kotlin, reference

I have a situation, where in Kotlin I want to take the *name* of a reference, modify it, and then call a function with the object, which corresponds with the modified name. For example:

```
val a = "Foo"
val aAlt = "Bar"

fun doSomething(s: String){ 
   println(s.*addAltToStringName()* ) 
}
```

So that by calling

```
doSomething(a)
```

the result is

```
Bar
```

I know, that doing something "untyped-scripty" like this in an object oriented language is dangerous, but I have other checks to prevent Nullpointers etc.

Thanks!

Comment: `String` is immutable, hence you can't literally do that. Your best call is to wrap that in a class which has a `var` String field and replace that string with the Sring you want,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with reflection, but only if the argument to the function is property reference, so you can get its name. The String object itself would provide no way to retrieve info about whatever variables might hold references to it. In other words, your property `a` references a String object, but that String object itself has no name or knowledge of the property that references it.

```
class Test {
    val a = "Foo"
    val aAlt = "Bar"

    fun doSomething(s: KProperty<*>){
        val propertyName = s.name + "Alt"
        val propertyValue = Test::class.memberProperties.find { it.name == propertyName }?.get(this)
        println(propertyValue)
    }
}

fun main() {
    val test = Test()
    test.doSomething(test::a)
}
```